# PHP AJAX resetting $_SESSION variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

I am making  simple php ajax chat and somehow my `$_SESSION['currentNum']` is unseting. 
The first php script`checkMessages.php` is checking for changes in mysql databes (raspberry pi- raspbian os).

```
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

    session_start();

class Message{
    public $name;
    public $surname;
    public $email;
    public $mesgVal;
    public $msgTime;
}

$dbhost = 'localhost:3036';
$dbuser = '******';
$dbpass = '*********';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn ){
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

if(!mysql_select_db('forum')){
    die("Database does not exist " . mysql_error());
}
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

$mesgList = array();

//first time when user is logged
if(!isset($_SESSION['currentNum'])){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM (
                SELECT  u.name, u.surname, u.email,m.id_message, m.value, m.ts 
                FROM users u, message m 
                WHERE m.user_id = u.id_user 
                ORDER BY m.id_message DESC LIMIT 10
                ) q 
            ORDER BY q.ts ASC;";

    $query = mysql_query($sql, $conn);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
            $item = new Message();
            $item->name = $row['name'];
            $item->surname = $row['surname'];
            $item->email = $row['email'];
            $item->mesgVal = $row['value'];
            $item->msgTime = $row['ts'];
            $mesgList[] = $item;
            $_SESSION['currentNum'] = $row['id_message'];
    }

    $currentNum = $_SESSION['currentNum'];
//rest of time      
}else{

    $currentNum = $_SESSION['currentNum'];
    $sql = "SELECT u.name, u.surname, u.email, m.value, m.ts 
            FROM users u, message m 
            WHERE m.user_id = u.id_user 
            AND m.id_message > '$currentNum' 
            ORDER BY m.id_message ASC";

    $query = mysql_query($sql, $conn);

    if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){

        //mysql_data_seek($query, 1);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
            $item = new Message();
            $item->name = $row['name'];
            $item->surname = $row['surname'];
            $item->email = $row['email'];
            $item->value = $row['value'];
            $item->msgTime = $row['ts'];
            $mesgList[] = $item;

            $_SESSION['currentNum'] = $row['id_message'];
        }
    }
}


echo json_encode($mesgList);

mysql_close($conn);
```

The next php script`saveMessage.php` is saving posted messages form user to database.

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

    session_start();
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$dbhost = 'localhost:3036';
$dbuser = '*********';
$dbpass = '************';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn ){
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

if(!mysql_select_db('forum')){
    die("Database does not exist " . mysql_error());
}
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");


$message = test($_POST['message']);


if($message !== ""){
    $logged = $_SESSION['login_user'];
    $idOfMessageWriter;

    $sql = "SELECT id_user FROM users WHERE email = '$logged'";
    $query = mysql_query($sql, $conn);

    if (!$query) {
        die("Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error());
    }
    while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
        $idOfMessageWriter = $row['id_user'];
    }


    $sql = "INSERT INTO message (value, user_id) VALUES ('$message','$idOfMessageWriter')";
    if(!mysql_query($sql, $conn)){
        die("Sprava neuložená" . mysql_error());
    }
}
function test($data){
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripcslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}



mysql_close($conn);
```

Next is javaScript code where JQuery's ajax is calling the scripts.

```
  $( document ).ready(function(){
    setInterval(check, 2000);

});

function check(){

    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:'checkMessages.php',
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(result){
            $("#messageBox").append(result);

            for(var i in result){
                $("#messageBox").append(result[i].email + ": " + result[i].mesgVal + "<br>");
            }
        },
        error: function(/*jqXHR, exception"*/ts){
            //  $('#sendInfo').html("Error check " + ts.responseText);
            }   
    });
}

function sendData(){

        var textData = $('#chatText').val();
        console.log(textData);
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'saveMessage.php',
            data: {
                message:textData
            },
            dataType: 'text',
            success: function(data){
                $('#sendInfo').html(data);
            },
            error: function(/*jqXHR, exception"*/ts){
                $('#sendInfo').html("Error send" + ts.responseText);
            }       
        });
}
```

function `sendData()` is called from html doc.

```
<input type="button" name="sendChatText" id="sendChatText" value="Odoslať" onClick="sendData()">
```

My problem is. When ajax and `checkMessages.php` are checking for changes in database , it works `$_SESSION['currentNum']` is set. But when i post message (`saveMessage.php` is called) `$_SESSION['currentNum']` unsets and i dont know why. Any ideas ?

UPDATE.. Problem was not in SESSION. In `checkMessages.php` the second SELECT was incorrect. Correct is

> SELECT u.name, u.surname, u.email, m.id_message, m.value, m.ts 
>                   FROM users u, message m 
>                   WHERE m.user_id = u.id_user 
>                   AND m.id_message > '$currentNum' 
>                   ORDER BY m.id_message ASC;

Comment: Are you start session with `session_start();`? [ http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-start.php ]

Comment: yes .. i do ... but when i post message, then $_SESSION['currentNum'] is reset

Comment: You open session at the beginning of each of the files `checkMessages.php` and `saveMessage.php`?

Comment: yes i do it in every file i use session things

Comment: Do not use `mysql_*` functions. They have been deprecated for over 3 years now

Comment: You are not using `$_SESSION['currentNum']` anywhere in savemessages.php. But it should not be a problem. Try adding `session_start()` in start.

Comment: Try to call `session_start()` right in the first line of every file... If you call `header()` before, you are outputting text before starting the session and it is probably causing that malfunction...

Comment: Now that you've identified that your problem was down to an SQL error, and had nothing to do with javascript, php, jquery, ajax or session, I'm not sure what value this question has.  If this issue, is a non-issue, consider deleting the question.

Comment: maybe some1 will find what he wants in this post...